# Jenkin Job not able to Push changes in Git

Tags: git, jenkins, containers

I have creaetd a free style Jenkin Job on containerized Jenkin which checkout code from git. Once code checkout I am creating a test file and commiting nack to git. wrriten code in shell:

```
echo "some data for the file" >>test.txt
git add -A
git commit -m "Added new file"
git status
git push origin master

But it gives error as :
+ git commit -m 'Added new file'
[detached HEAD f0a4575] Added new file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
+ git status
# HEAD detached from 7090e78
nothing to commit, working directory clean
+ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to generate a SSH keypair with ssh-keygen command in your local machine. This will generate both public and private SSH keys.

Upload the public key to your repository, and store the private key in your Jenkins Credentials Manager with a custom ID of your choice.

In your job, you will need to [inject this secret as a parameter](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs), and put its contents here:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If this doesn't work you may need to add the key with sshagent. You have here an example for GitHub: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Anyway, if managing SSH keys is a pain for you, you can store user and password as Credentials in Jenkins as well, then authentication is quite easy with a simple basic auth mechanism:

`git push https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@yourRepoUrl.com/repo`

Comment: I have already generated ssh key and add public key on github and private key on Jenkin.if you see the log I am able to checkout code from git but not able to push

Comment: You're correct, SSH keys are already created. Then the only part missing is injecting the credential using the job configuration, to be able to use it in the bash script and push back to the git remote. Once you have the key you can do ssh-add -K <your_key_location> and push should work.